# Referring values in a matrix (extended)

Tags: r

I have some R code from a friend that takes a numeric vector, and for each number checks if the number is the same upside down.

```
numbers = (0:9)
upside_down_numbers = c(0,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,9,NA,8,6)
ref_table = rbind(numbers,upside_down_numbers)
invertible = function(n){
   as.numeric(paste0(
    upside_down_numbers[
      1+rev(as.numeric(strsplit(as.character(n),"")[[1]]))
      ],collapse=""))}
```

I want it to return TRUE if the number entered is the same as the number returned
for example:

```
invertible(69)
[1] 69
```

and FALSE if the number entered is different to the number returned or returns NA
for example:

```
invertible(99)
[66]
```

I also want the code to be able to work on multiple numbers
for example:

```
invertible(c(1, 96, 99, 123, 1691))
[1] TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE
```

Really stuck at this point, would appreciate some advice. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is definitely an unusual task... but this will work for you.

```
invertible_test <- function(n) {
  inverted <- suppressWarnings(invertible(n))
  if (is.na(inverted)) {
    return(FALSE)
  }
  return(n == inverted)
}

invertible_test_vector <- function(v) {
  vapply(v, invertible_test, c(T))
}
```

Here it passes your test:

```
invertible_test_vector(c(1, 96, 99, 123, 1691))
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the `invertible` function with logical return values.  It seems like that's what you were asking for, but not sure.

---

**Updated:**  This is a better function than the one I wrote earlier. And it's vectorized over `n`

```
invertible <- function(n)
{
    spl <- lapply(strsplit(as.character(n), NULL), rev)
    s <- sapply(spl, function(x) paste(udn[1 + as.numeric(x)], collapse = ""))
    s == n
}

> udn <- c(0, 1, rep(NA, 4), 9, NA, 8, 6)
> n <- c(1, 96, 99, 123, 1691)
> invertible(n)
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

But an even nicer way to write this would be to for a single numeric argument and then use the `Vectorize` function

```
invertible <- Vectorize(function(n) {
    spl <- rev(unlist(strsplit(as.character(n), NULL)))
    paste(udn[1 + as.numeric(spl)], collapse = "") == n
})
```

Comment: i believe it makes the upside_down_numbers vector correspond to the numbers vector. 1 to 1, 2 to Na etc..